# Converting Integer to Character in Swift

Tags: swift

How can i convert an integer say 0 to a , 1 to b , 2 to c in Swift . I know in C++ and Python but could not find a straight forward way in swift

C++ code below

```
  char a = 0 + 97;
  char b = 1 + 97;
```

Comment: It depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve, but the general answer is: "don't do this". Most of the world's characters (by both quantity and frequency of use) aren't ASCII. You shouldn't be hard coding things like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the same thing in Swift like this:

```
let a = Character(UnicodeScalar(0 + 97))
let b = Character(UnicodeScalar(1 + 97))
```